# Visual Studio 2010 Solution Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I am not able to see the files that I **'Exclude'** from my project, in the Solution Explorer(VS 2010).
How do I get them back?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to turn `Show All Files` options on. There's icon in Solution Explorer for that. Click on project or file in solution explorer and this icon should appear - it's second from left.