# How to list files that aren't in any project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I have a Visual Studio solution and projects in a folder. I suspect there are also some `.cs` files in that folder that aren't in any project. How can I list them?

Comment: Are you referring to files in the folder itself? You could right right-click the folder and select "Open Folder in File Explorer" to see everything.

Comment: possible dublicate: [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348849/visual-studio-2010-solution-explorer)

Comment: also, in solution explorer, theres an icon at the top that will "Show all files" in the folder

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clicking the "Show All Files" in solution explorer will show all files

The files not in the solution will have a dotted icon

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there anyway I can list all such files without having to peer through the solution explorer? It's a big solution.

Comment: I don't believe a functionality like this exist in VS. You might be able to roll your own using the visual studio DTE -> have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434720/get-a-list-of-solution-project-files-for-vs-add-in-or-dxcore-plugin . List the active files in solution-> list files in folder -> filter to *.cs and compare